# open graph image url problems with converted special chars XKB Symbols

Tags: facebook-opengraph, htmlspecialchars

I try to use the like-Button and therefor the open graph.

My problem is, that "&" and "$" chars are always replaced by & and %24

Of course, thats the normal case, but I need a clean $ and no entity there, becuase otherwise the link is not working for this image.

I could see, that facebook´s raw output produces \u0024 and so on (seems to be XKBSymbols). But if I try to put this symbols in the link in my typo3 meta-tag, it doesnt work either.

I already tried:

```
#page.headerData.12345.htmlSpecialChars = 0
#page.headerData.12345.htmlSpecialChars.preserveEntities = 1
#page.headerData.12345.rawUrlEncode = 0
```

to solve this problem, but none of those work.

Please give me a useful hint.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to write to your php code trough htmlspecialchar php function and add it to header with
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->additionalHeaderData['somekey'] = '...'